# HTML page template for multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a somewhat extensive website and have not worked with web development in a while. I would like to create a basic layout for every page on the site. That is, I would like to create a header, footer, nav bars, and standard containers that will be the same across all the pages on the site.

However, I do not want to simply copy and paste code. Is there a method to create a basic central page template that I can edit and have changes go in effect across all pages?

Comment: Check out a tutorial for PHP Includes.

Comment: which framework and technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

Create **header.php** **navigation.php** **footer.php** then just include them in any file where you need.

i.e.

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'navigation.php'; ?>
</div>
<div>
Some central content here
</div>
<div>
<?php include 'footer.php'?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when you change the header.php its changes will be reflected in every page where you included it.

One more thing I want to mention it is better if you use some MVC Framework. In it there is default.ctp concept. Where you can create common templates for pages.

More about MVC framework [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Will the elements that I include in the php files be accessible through CSS? Or is that taken care of in the PHP files?

Comment: You should include css at the top of header file and work normal on css. as you work in html page.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap, a sleek, intuitive, and powerful mobile first front-end framework for faster and easier web development

http://getbootstrap.com/

Bootstrap is a templating system which may help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely look into bootstrap.